# Unable to convert 3d ply file image to 2d image

Tags: python, image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network, depth-buffer

I am really stuck at this point and want to convert my 3d face image to 2d image for depth label to my FCN.

I have gone through this link to generate my 3dmm model face image.

https://github.com/Yinghao-Li/3DMM-fitting

Any help will really get me through.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like [pyrender](https://pyrender.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/quickstart.html).

For documentation purposes here's one of their example:

```
import numpy as np
import trimesh
import pyrender
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fuze_trimesh = trimesh.load('examples/models/fuze.obj')
mesh = pyrender.Mesh.from_trimesh(fuze_trimesh)
scene = pyrender.Scene()
scene.add(mesh)
camera = pyrender.PerspectiveCamera(yfov=np.pi / 3.0, aspectRatio=1.0)
s = np.sqrt(2)/2
camera_pose = np.array([
   [0.0, -s,   s,   0.3],
   [1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
   [0.0,  s,   s,   0.35],
   [0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
])
scene.add(camera, pose=camera_pose)
light = pyrender.SpotLight(color=np.ones(3), intensity=3.0,
                           innerConeAngle=np.pi/16.0,
                           outerConeAngle=np.pi/6.0)
scene.add(light, pose=camera_pose)
r = pyrender.OffscreenRenderer(400, 400)
color, depth = r.render(scene)
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(color)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(depth, cmap=plt.cm.gray_r)
plt.show()
```

[image: pyrender example]

or [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/Basic/visualization.html).

Again, one of the library supplied examples:

```
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("../../TestData/fragment.ply")
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd], zoom=0.3412,
                                  front=[0.4257, -0.2125, -0.8795],
                                  lookat=[2.6172, 2.0475, 1.532],
                                  up=[-0.0694, -0.9768, 0.2024])
```

[image: Open3D PLY model]